# jQuery Children giving undefined result

Tags: jquery

So, I have the following markup:

```
<a class=" rhpcon" href="#">
   <div class="rhccont">Content</div>
</a>


jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.rhpcon', function(e) {  
    var rhccont= jQuery(this).children().find('.rhccont').html();   
    alert(rhccont);                         
});
```

However, I keep getting "Undefined" as the alert.

I am guessing it is the `children` that is wrong.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `.children()` as `.find()` searches the descendant elements. Use:

```
var rhccont= jQuery(this).find('.rhccont').html();
```

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', '.rhpcon', function(e) {
  var rhccont = jQuery(this).find('.rhccont').html();
  alert(rhccont);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class=" rhpcon" href="#">
  <div class="rhccont">Content</div>
</a>
```

You could also use `.children()` instead of `.find()` like:

```
var rhccont= jQuery(this).children('.rhccont').html();
```

But again, not both together. As the documentation on these functions states:

> The `.find()` and `.children()` methods are similar, except that the
>   latter only travels a single level down the DOM tree.

Comment: Ah, i see. Appropriate usage of `children` is confusing haha. Thanks for the help! =) And than you for the clarification of `.find()`.